# Runtime game values class

Tags: libgdx

I'm newbie on libgdx and game developing logic. So i need your advice.

Here is my problem. I'm trying to make a game and i need to know how should i collect game values. Like hp, coins, score, attack speed ect. There's two side on my game. Player and enemy. I made two classes, LeftSide(this is player) and RightSide(this is enemy). Then i notice i didn't take user name and i can not think about this. What should i do? Should one class be optimized? or Should more classes, like i said before for player and enemy and maybe user's names.

Edit:

I ask this question because i don't know whis is most good for performance.

Comment: It isn't clear at all what you are asking. Can you provide some sample code?

Comment: i'm sorry for my bad english :(

Here's my question's picture:
http://img849.imageshack.us/img849/6581/tq0r.png

and my question is, which is give me most performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 2 is cleaner, if only because it can be factored down to two instances of a player class. Option 1 will be harder to maintain and will likely have duplicated logic.